# Driving servo motor with PWM signal

Tags: pwm, servo, duty-cycle

I want to drive servo motor with PWM signal.Servo motor rotation angle changes with the ratio of the duty cycle.Generally , servo motor rotation angle  according to PWM  can be seen in figure below.[image]

Suppose that

1. I apply duty cycle with 1ms  but Vmax=12V and V min =-12V
2. I apply same duty cycle but Vmax=12V and Vmin=0V .

In both cases ,will I obtain same rotation angle on the servo motor?If not ,Is there spesific Vmax and Vmin voltage to rotate servo like in figure above?

Comment: What device are you using that utilizes PWM? (e.g. is it an Arduino, etc.?)

Comment: what does this mean? `servo motor`

Comment: I obtain square wave by using  negative resistance converter with capacitor then I integrate square wave by using integrator op amp and finally by comparing integrator output with reference voltage I obtain PWM

Comment: Some motors are polar and others are bipolar for supply and control.  Which do you have?

Comment: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1-10x-SG90-9G-Micro-Gear-Servo-Motor-Remote-Control-RC-Robot-Helicopter-Airplane-/282696826700      @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: all it says is 4.8V

Comment: I find that it is polar @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: If you apply +/-12V to a 4.8V servo you probably won't get rotation. Smoke, maybe.

Comment: I got it.But I thought that when I apply +12V with %10 duty cycle I would apply 2.4 V and it is smaller than 5V. I understand I was wrong . @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to manual... which you can find on web
[image]

> Degree (') Position  for 50Hz cycle rate.
>   -90 ' ~1ms pulse - all the way to the left
>    0 ' 1.5 ms pulse - in the middle
>    90 ' ~2ms pulse - all the way to the right.

Comment: those wire colours are not standard, red/black/white, and other schemes, are also used.